# XAMPP - Only allow access to a directory locally

Tags: windows, apache, xampp

I have been stuck on this for days with no luck. I recently installed windows server 2008 and XAMPP. I got the 403 error and was able to edit the config file to allow al network access. I recently uploaded a billing system I made to the htdocs directory. Due to security issues, I want the admin directory to only be accessed through my local network.

Please show me how to do this if you know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do that through the apache configrations httpd.conf

```
<LocationMatch "^/domain.com/admin/*">
Order Deny,Allow 
Deny from all 
Allow from 192.168.*  
</LocationMatch>
```